# Virtualbox Linux host: Pass non-recognized USB device through to Windows guest

Tags: windows, linux, usb, virtualbox

I'm running [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) [4.1.2](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_1) (with the corresponding extension pack)  on an up-to-date Ubuntu 11.10 host with Windows XP as a guest. I have a National Instruments USB-6251 device which I would like to use with my Windows guest OS. (since MATLAB's DAQ toolbox is [only available in Windows](http://www.mathworks.se/products/daq/requirements.html))

NI does offer an [RPM based driver installer](http://joule.ni.com/nidu/cds/view/p/id/2893/lang/en), but the installer is giving me headaches because it can't find GLIBC since the "RPM database isn't populated" and when I bypass that error with the installer's `--nodeps` option, it fails saying that a 3.0 kernel is not supported and that I need a 2.6 kernel. Due to, at least, these two hurdles I'd rather not waste more time trying to set up a Linux driver when I don't need to use the device with Linux.

Running `lsusb` displays the device as

```
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 3923:72a0 National Instruments Corp.
```

and running `lsusb -d 3923: -v` returns a [bunch of information](http://pastebin.com/851v1Xwg).

But right-clicking the USB device icon in the virtual machine window's status bar indicates no device is connected.

[image: No USB devices connected context-menu]

Who can I get the Windows guest OS to see the device?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As often I found my answer while writing up the question. Posted it anway so others might benefit.

Turns out the issue wasn't that Linux didn't recognize the device, as I intially thought, but simply that my user didn't have enough permissions to access USB devices in general. Running

```
usermod -a -G vboxusers username
```

as suggested by Virtualbox, and then logging in and out, got it working.

[image]

Comment: Just be careful with usermod. If you don't use the right flags, you end up wiping out your groups.